# How best to implement rooms for a text-based game?

Tags: python

I was thinking of making a text-based game about detectives, case-solving, with complete freedom, loads of variables, etc.

But before I get serious with it I need to know how to make rooms. E.g. you start in the hall and you type in `"Go kitchen"` and you go to the kitchen.

I have achieved this by using `import file` when you type in `"Go kitchen"`  (the file is the kitchen file), but if I want to go back and forth between them it gives an error.

Is there something I am missing about this method? Is there a better way to do it? The simpler, the better, please.

Comment: This question as it stands is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. If you show your current code, we can explain what is going wrong, but we're not really here to answer really broad questions like "how best to do this vague thing". Any answer is almost entirely opinion. My personal suggestion would be to use OOP and make each room an instance of a `Room` class (or a subclass if it needs custom code), but I'm sure there are other equally good ways to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `import` to implement application logic.

In your use case, a room is the classic example of an object in object-oriented programming. You should have a class `Room` which defines the functionality for rooms. Individual rooms are instances of that class (later you can add subclasses, but I would not worry about that initially).

Your application will have a "current room" as a variable. It will ask the room about its description and display that to the user. When the user types "go Kitchen", your application will ask the current room "hey, do you have a room named 'Kitchen' as a neighbor?" This method will return the appropriate room object, which your application then can set as the current room.

From the above, you can see two functionalities (methods) rooms should have: "Give me your description" and "give me the adjacent room named 'X', if any".

This should get you started.